# Where is the Pear PHPUnit command

Tags: pear

As you see in the image below, I have Pear installed, and there is a PhpUnit folder, but when I run this code (from a book on Yii),

```
    % phpunit functional/SiteTest.php
```

it's telling me

```
-bash: phpunit: command not found
```

I am assuming from the fact that Phpunit folder is present that I have correctly installed it. In fact, it said install o.k. in the terminal.

Any ideas where I can find this command?

[image]

Comment: Does `whereis phpunit` work under mac? If you find it, you may link it into a directory covered by `PATH` (I guess, it exists under mac too).

Comment: whereis phpunit just gives me a new prompt. I'm not sure if that means it wasn't found, or the command whereis doesn't work on Mac

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Running

```
pear config-get bin_dir
```

will tell you the location where PEAR installs executables (like `phpunit`) to.

Having gotten the directory name, you want to add it to your PATH. One way to do this is to edit the `.profile` file in your home directory (it's hidden), and add the following line:

```
export PATH=<dir you got from pear config-get>:$PATH
```

and then either close and re-open your terminal, or run `. ~/.profile`.

Comment: thanks, it gave me a response /Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin but I put that in my php.ini include path and the command I'm looking for is still not found.

Comment: In this case, it's not the PHP include path you need to modify, but your `PATH` environment variable, which determines what commands you can run by name alone from the terminal.

Comment: I put, export PATH=/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin:$PATH, into .bash_profile and ran the command but still phpunit not found.

Comment: .bash_profile will work just as well, I simply remembered .profile as being the one that more often already existed for Mac users.

Comment: If you want to make sure you've got the right directory and that phpunit is correctly installed, you could try just executing phpunit with its (presumed) full path. So instead of running `phpunit`, try running `/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/phpunit`, which should work if phpunit's binary was indeed installed to that directory.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped.  I was looking everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Since I had the same problem although phpunit installed successfully (it seemed) `phpunit` command was missing. After some research I found following comment: [How do I correctly install PHPUnit with PEAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536668/how-do-i-correctly-install-phpunit-with-pear#comment16899314_12545727), so after:

```
$ sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com # mind the difference!
$ sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit

$ which phpunit
/usr/local/pear/bin/phpunit
```

everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

- pear uninstall phpunit
- pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
- pear channel-discover components.ez.no
- pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
- pear install phpunit/PHPUnit

and if I remember correctly you also need to install the curl extension to be able to install phpunit.

Tyrael

Comment: phpunit depends on curl.
to be exact, phpunit depends on XML_RPC2, which depends on curl.
see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.5/package.xml and http://pear.php.net/package/XML_RPC2/

Comment: reported that to Sebastian, and got it fixed: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/266#comment_1332465