# How do I correctly install PHPUnit with PEAR?

Tags: php, symfony1, phpunit, yaml, pear

I have had to de- and reinstall a newer version of PHPUnit following [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186000/call-to-undefined-method-php-codecoverage-filtergetinstance/9407628#9407628). Now when I'm launching this line

```
sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

I see an error message, that looks like this.

```
Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony.com
phpunit/PHPUnit requires package "channel://pear.symfony.com/Yaml" (version >= 2.1.0)
No valid packages found
```

If I install just Yaml by launching

```
sudo pear install symfony/YAML
```

an older version (1.0.6) will be installed that doesn't meet the dependency of PHPUnit. How can I possibly solve this?

Comment: Pear is giving me troubles. This solved it for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/451953/php-pear-is-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04/451975#451975

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I had the same problem while upgrading my phpunit.

This solved the problem:

```
pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml
```

Then run:

```
pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

OBS: I think the `pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml` is not necessary. I'm just posting it because it is exactly the way I solved my problem.

Comment: This actually worked and now I understand why it didn't beforehand. The symfony project operates two different pear channels. [http://pear.symfony-project.com/](http://pear.symfony-project.com/) is for version 1 and [http://pear.symfony.com/](http://pear.symfony.com/) for version 2. Only the latter contains YAML2, which is needed by PHPUnit. Thanks, PutzKipa!

Comment: And yes the command `pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml` hasn't been necessary to install PHPUnit.

Comment: I also had to download the CodeCoverage from Github repo https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage and link to it in the PHPUnit directory: sudo mv ./PHP/CodeCoverage.php ./PHP/CodeCoverage.php.bak;  
sudo ln -s /home/my-cloned-github-repo-dir/php-code-coverage/PHP/CodeCoverage.php ./PHP/CodeCoverage.php;
sudo ln -s /home/my-cloned-github-repo-dir/PHP/CodeCoverage ./PHP/CodeCoverage; # "I'm on ubuntu 12.04"

Comment: This process also didn't solve the problem I stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797778/installing-doctrine2-with-pear?lq=1). YAML was being installed with backdated versions. And the other components of Doctrine too.

Answer (score 10):

Use this, as described [in the PHPUnit docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.pear): (i don't what sudo means, this is how I do it on a windows PC):

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Comment: Brilliant! I always had trouble finding the channels PHPUnit required and I install it frequently

Comment: Awesome. You saved me of three days headache. I had to go and upvote all your answers :)

Answer (score 5):

I also had this error message:

> Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony.com

Solved creating an alias:

```
pear channel-alias pear.symfony-project.com pear.symfony.com
```

and then

```
channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com

sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no

sudo pear update-channels

sudo pear upgrade-all

sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Comment: This process also didn't help solve mine. But I solved in a different way [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797778/installing-doctrine2-with-pear?lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

First: `locate pear` you may have multiple versions installed and this could be a pain.

At work we have something like this in our intranet:

```
sudo [your pear install] channel-update pear.php.net  
sudo [your pear install] upgrade pear  
sudo [your pear install] channel-discover pear.phpunit.de  
sudo [your pear install] install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

I know theres a more automated way to install it using: go-pear ( http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php )

However, if you already have some other install of pear it will totally wreck everything and you'll spend quite some time trying to fix it. I think the biggest hurdle is being able to tell all the libraries where each other is.

Comment: Didn't help in resetting PEAR for this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797778/installing-doctrine2-with-pear?lq=1). Expecting your answer there. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pear install -a phpunit
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
```

I had similar problem complaining about "Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony.com".
had to do (without sudo, I got weird error about cannot open some file)

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
```

then

```
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Now I can see phpunit in my /usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

Process mentioned by PutzKipa works however you might need super user privileges. For ubuntu add sudo before each command.

Answer (score 0):

Following Plínio César, I solved it finally, but with slight variation:

First I did a "sudo apt-get remove phpunit" to remove the faulty installation.   Then using pear to do the phpunit installation:

sudo pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml

sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de

sudo  pear config-set auto_discover 1

sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

Thanks Plinio Cesar!!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to obtain PHPUnit in Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora or OpenSUSE is to download a PHP Archive (PHAR) that has all required (as well as some optional) dependencies of PHPUnit bundled in a single file.

Open the terminal and type:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar  # download the PHP Archive (PHAR) file  
chmod +x phpunit.phar   
sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

There are many different versions of phpunit.phar at https://phar.phpunit.de/. If you use the first command, it will select and download the latest version.

Note: The `/usr/local/bin/` path in the last command is correct for Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora and OpenSUSE distributions and also for other Linux distributions that have a `/usr/local/bin/` directory.

<sub>Reference: [What is /usr/local/bin? Came across it in an script installation for Applescript but would like to know more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/what-is-usr-local-bin-came-across-it-in-an-script-installation-for-applescript)</sub>