# Installing Doctrine2 with PEAR

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pear, failed-installation

While I tried this:
`sudo pear install -o pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineORM`

I got the following error:

```
    Package "pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineORM" dependency  "pear.symfony.com/Console" has no releases
    Package "pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineDBAL" dependency "pear.symfony.com/Console" has no releases
    doctrine/DoctrineORM requires package "pear.symfony.com/Console" (version >= 2.0.0)
    doctrine/DoctrineORM requires package "pear.symfony.com/Yaml" (version >= 2.0.0), installed version is 1.0.6
    doctrine/DoctrineDBAL requires package "pear.symfony.com/Console" (version >= 2.0.0)
    No valid packages found
    install failed
```

Solved the above by doing the following:
`sudo apt-get purge php-pear`

Ended up in results like:

```
    Removing php-pear ...
    Purging configuration files for php-pear ...
    dpkg: warning: while removing php-pear, directory '/usr/share/doc/php5-common/PEAR' not empty so not removed
    dpkg: warning: while removing php-pear, directory '/usr/share/php/.channels' not empty so not removed
```

Same was for the following folders:

```
    /usr/share/php/.registry/
    /usr/share/php/.channels/.alias
    /usr/share/php/data
    /usr/share/doc/php5-common/PEAR/Archive_Tar/docs
    /usr/share/doc/php5-common/PEAR
```

So I removed them all and then purged `php-pear` completely and reinstalled it again.

now, `sudo pear channel-discover pear.doctrine-project.org` also didn't say channel already in registry and the later steps also succeeded.

Though I have solved my problem in the above steps. While I failed using the suggestions stated at comments and answers to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536668/how-do-i-correctly-install-phpunit-with-pear/13620648#13620648)

But I am just curious what could have been wrong in the first place. How PEAR wasn't being able to fetch proper versions of Doctrine2?

Even the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12545727/799845)'s process didn't help.

Comment: I had [posted this as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536668/how-do-i-correctly-install-phpunit-with-pear/13620648#13620648) as I was able to get rid of the PEAR problem I was having. But it was deleted while I thought the process I followed could have solved someone though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem as this topic states but with Doctrine pear installation.

While I try this:
`sudo pear install -o pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineORM`

I get the following error:

```
        Package "pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineORM" dependency  "pear.symfony.com/Console" has no releases
        Package "pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineDBAL" dependency "pear.symfony.com/Console" has no releases
        doctrine/DoctrineORM requires package "pear.symfony.com/Console" (version >= 2.0.0)
        doctrine/DoctrineORM requires package "pear.symfony.com/Yaml" (version >= 2.0.0), installed version is 1.0.6
        doctrine/DoctrineDBAL requires package "pear.symfony.com/Console" (version >= 2.0.0)
        No valid packages found
        install failed
```

I have applied what @Paulo and @Parris suggested in another SO QA. But that did not help. Posting it here just for the record.

Edit:

Solved the above by doing the following:
`sudo apt-get purge php-pear`

Ended up in results like:

```
        Removing php-pear ...
        Purging configuration files for php-pear ...
        dpkg: warning: while removing php-pear, directory '/usr/share/doc/php5-common/PEAR' not empty so not removed
        dpkg: warning: while removing php-pear, directory '/usr/share/php/.channels' not empty so not removed
```

Same was for the following folders:

```
        /usr/share/php/.registry/
        /usr/share/php/.channels/.alias
        /usr/share/php/data
        /usr/share/doc/php5-common/PEAR/Archive_Tar/docs
        /usr/share/doc/php5-common/PEAR
```

So I removed them all and then purged `php-pear` completely and reinstalled it again.

now, `sudo pear channel-discover pear.doctrine-project.org` also didn't say channel already in registry and the later steps also succeeded.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You should have upgraded the `pear.symfony.com/Yaml` package. PEAR listed version 2.0.0 as requirement, but you only had 1.0.6:

```
$ pear upgrade symfony/yaml
```

Also, it did not find (compatible) releases of `pear.symfony.com/console` - this was the main reason for the failure. A solution would have been a `pear clear-cache` call, followed by a possible `pear channel-update pear.symfony.com` call. After that, the console dep should be installed automatically.

Comment: What is the way to upgrade in such situation (ie for Yaml). I did the channel-update but didn't do a `pear clear-cache`.